# Android Resolve Uri failed on bad bitmap Uri error

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm creating a camera application and in the main activity it's retrieve the camera preview bitmap and save to the internal storage.after intent to another class I want to display the image by getting the path of the bitmap.however after taking the picture for the first time, it's displays the picture well but sometimes not display the image and gives the following error

```
"Resolve Uri failed on bad bitmap Uri : data/data/com.camera.app/files/287372639100.jpg"
```

mainclass

```
                //IMG name
                mName = System.currentTimeMillis();
                dTime  = mName;

                try {
                    //get bitmap & save into internal storage
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = IN_SAMPLE_SIZE;
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);

                    try {
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(dTime+".jpg");
                        File f = new File(uri.toString());
                        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
                        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                        int angle = 0;

                        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                            angle = 90;
                        } 
                        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                            angle = 180;
                        } 
                        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                            angle = 270;
                        }
                        else{
                            angle = 0;
                        }

                        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
                        mat.postRotate(angle);
                        //get rotated bitmap
                        Bitmap correctBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mat, true);                 

                        //save bitmap to internal storage
                        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(dTime+".jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        correctBmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
                        correctBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 380, 600, false);
                        fos.close();

                        bitmap.recycle();
                        correctBmp.recycle();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.w("TAG", "-- Error in setting image");
                    }   
                    catch(OutOfMemoryError oom) {
                        Log.w("TAG", "-- OOM Error in setting image");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // intent send data
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PhotoClass.class);
                intent.putExtra("IMG_NAME", dTime);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - bitmap sending..");
```

Photoclass

```
        //get intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        imgName = intent.getLongExtra("IMG_NAME", 0);
        uri = Uri.parse(getFilesDir().getPath() + "/"+imgName+".jpg");

        if(imgName != 0){
            mImagePreView.setImageURI(uri);
        }
```

need a help to solve this problem.